# Loading a dictionary property list generated by the codesign tool on OS X

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, plist, nsdictionary

I'm working on a simple project but I've bumped up against a wall with a seemingly easy task. Loading a dictionary-rooted plist into a NSDirectory. This is something I've done plenty of times before so I'm a bit puzzled as to why I'm currently stuck.

I'm attempting to read in a plist that I created with the codesign tool on OS X. The invocation of that tool I'm using dumps the app entitlements to a file. In the case of Safari it would do this:

```
codesign --display --entitlements :<path to plist> /Applications/Safari.app
```

This generates a normal XML plist at my specified path. You need the colon prefix so that it doesn't insert a magic binary blob at the beginning of the file. The full XML for the plist generated looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.private.accounts.allaccounts</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier</key>
    <string>com.apple.Safari.SyncedTabs</string>
    <key>com.apple.private.tcc.allow</key>
    <array>
            <string>kTCCServiceAddressBook</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Simple right? So now I just want to load this into a NSDictionary. I simply try to load it in the normal way:

```
NSDictionary *entitlementDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:tempFile];
```

What happens though is that it refuses to load anything and I get a nil for contents:

```
Printing description of entitlementDict:
<nil>
(lldb)
```

I feel like I'm missing something obvious here. I know that the NSDictionary loading methods only work if all the contents are plist-objects, but it looks like they are and Xcode and QuickLook will happily show me the contents of the file. Additionally plutil validates that the syntax is correct.

Any ideas? Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to the folks who have answered so far. For more information I am using the proper full path.

From the debugger:

```
Printing description of tempFile:
/var/folders/yk/kvvzp89x03v896rqx4mc9rqw0000gq/T/FFF82FDD-0A01-4139-9719-00B447B2F907-60198-000284518B41D04F/BC54EEC8-5A0B-49FD-9BFD-44B7FFB29B73.plist
```

And from the terminal:

```
FatMan:~ macshome$ file /var/folders/yk/kvvzp89x03v896rqx4mc9rqw0000gq/T/FFF82FDD-0A01-4139-9719-00B447B2F907-60198-000284518B41D04F/BC54EEC8-5A0B-49FD-9BFD-44B7FFB29B73.plist
/var/folders/yk/kvvzp89x03v896rqx4mc9rqw0000gq/T/FFF82FDD-0A01-4139-9719-00B447B2F907-60198-000284518B41D04F/BC54EEC8-5A0B-49FD-9BFD-44B7FFB29B73.plist: XML  document text
```

and:

```
FatMan:~ macshome$ ls -l /var/folders/yk/kvvzp89x03v896rqx4mc9rqw0000gq/T/FFF82FDD-0A01-4139-9719-00B447B2F907-60198-000284518B41D04F/BC54EEC8-5A0B-49FD-9BFD-44B7FFB29B73.plist
-rw-r--r--  1 macshome  staff  455 Jan 12 15:13 /var/folders/yk/kvvzp89x03v896rqx4mc9rqw0000gq/T/FFF82FDD-0A01-4139-9719-00B447B2F907-60198-000284518B41D04F/BC54EEC8-5A0B-49FD-9BFD-44B7FFB29B73.plist
```

I can post the code that generates my temp path, but I don't really think it matters much. Maybe I'll try testing with a shorter path, but I don't think that matters much either. This is a pretty typical way to generate a temp file.

**Final update:**
I figured out what I was doing wrong, although I wish it was a more interesting answer.

I'm calling the codesign tool with a NSTask, but in my basic testing I was forgetting to wait until it completed before attempting to load the plist into my NSDictionary. If I just use the termination handler or waitUntilExit or the termination notification then everything works as expected.

Many thanks to those who tried to help!

Comment: I validated that i can generate the `NSDictionary` from your file.  Try eliminating possibilities, definitely try a shorter path.

Comment: I'll try that when I get back in a bit. Perhaps you could try generating the file with the codesign tool like I did? I'm wondering if it has something to do with the generated file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what I was doing wrong, although I wish it was a more interesting answer.

I'm calling the codesign tool with a NSTask, but in my basic testing I was forgetting to wait until it completed before attempting to load the plist into my NSDictionary. If I just use the termination handler or waitUntilExit or the termination notification then everything works as expected.

Many thanks to those who tried to help!

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem you were having and i think it's because you're not getting the path to the file correctly.  When I changed the test to do the following, it worked.

```
   NSDictionary *entitlementDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"DictionaryTest.plist"]];
```

From the docs:

```
+ (id) dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path
```

> Parameters
>
> path
>
> A full or relative pathname. The file identified by path must contain
>   a string representation of a property list whose root object is a
>   dictionary.
>
> Return Value
>
> A new dictionary that contains the dictionary at path, or nil if there
>   is a file error or if the contents of the file are an invalid
>   representation of a dictionary.

Comment: Well he used "tempFile", how you know it's not the full path?

Comment: because i got the exact same problem until i changed to what i have in the answer. ;)  Copied his xml verbatim.